# Dropping privileges from perl script?

Tags: linux, perl, bash

I have a perl script running as root, and from within it I want to execute a system command `bar` as a lesser priveleged user `foo`.  So I have my `system` call wrapped as follows:

```
sub dosys
{
        system(@_) == 0
                or die "system @_ failed: $?";
}
```

And so I want to say:

```
as user foo dosys("bar")
```

Is there a mechanism within perl or the underlying bash shell that I can use to do this?  (I would prefer one that didn't require installing an additional cpan library if possible)

Answer (score 4):

The [`POSIX`](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html) module is a Perl core module, and it includes the functions:

- `setuid()`
- `setgid()`

and related `get*id()` functions, though the values are also available through special variables:

- `$)` and `$(` (effective and real GID)
- `$<` and `$>` (effective and real UID)

You can also try setting those directly (per [$EGID](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24EGID) and [$UID](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24UID)).

Comment: Just remember to comment your code if you're using those variables :) Por favor.

Comment: @JoeFrambach or he can `use English`.

Comment: @jordanm You should use `use English '-no_match_vars';` if you are going to use [English](http://perldoc.perl.org/English.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
system('su www-data -c whoami')
> www-data
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change groups first, remember to quash supplementary groups, and then change user.  You'll want to do this in a separate process, so that the [UG]ID changing doesn't affect privs on your root process.

```
sub su_system {
  my $acct = shift;
  my $gid = getgrnam $acct; # XXX error checking!
  my $uid = getpwnam $acct;

  if (fork) {               # XXX error checking!
    wait;
    return $? >> 8;
  }

  # -- child
  $( = $) = "$gid $gid";    # No supp. groups; see perlvar $)
  $< = $> = $uid;

  exec @_;  # XXX not as safe as exec {prog} @argv
            #     oh, and what if $acct had [ug]id zero?  darn
}
```

Proceed with caution.